# Setting up router: I can get online via Ethernet, and I can connect to router wirelessly, but can't get online wirelessly

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, ethernet

I'm setting up a new D-Link N300 router, and trying to connect a MacBook Pro and a MacBook, both running OS X 10.6.

As the question says, either computer can connect to the internet when connected to the router via Ethernet. And either one can get on the router's wireless network. But when connected wirelessly (without the Ethernet cable plugged in), neither one can get online.

I can't figure out why that would be. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you verified that "either one can get on the router's wireless network"? Things to check:

- Check your wired and wireless connections for how they acquire their IP address -- is one or the other configured to use a static/manual IP address vs DHCP assigned IP address?
- Are you sure you're connecting to the correct wireless router?
- Plug in the ethernet cable and turn on the wireless. In a Terminal window, run `ifconfig en0` (wired connection) and `ifconfig en1` (wireless). Are the IP addresses in the same block?

Next steps after verifying that stuff:

- Is it a DNS problem? Check that your wired and wireless connections are using the same DNS servers. With each connection enabled, look at the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`. If they're different, that could be the cause.
- Do you have custom routing set up somehow for wireless? Compare the output of `netstat -r` when you're on wired vs wireless connection.

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance—It was different DNS settings, as it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your cable modem.

You didn't mention how you're connecting to the internet but if you're connecting using cable or DSL, try rebooting all the pieces.

It sounds goofy because you're able to connect using ethernet but...